# Android animated vector rotation - properly starting animation

Tags: android, animation, vector

I'm using `<animated-vector>` to rotate an arrow:

```
<target
    android:name="rotationGroup"
    android:animation="@animator/animator" />
```

and the animator:

```
 <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:valueFrom="180"
        android:valueTo="0"/>
```

And the vector that I'm transforming.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24">

    <group
        android:name="rotationGroup"
        android:pivotX="12"
        android:pivotY="12"
        android:rotation="0.0">
        <group
            android:translateX="7.0"
            android:translateY="9.0">
            <path
                android:fillColor="@color/sc_item_filter_list_chevron"
                android:pathData="M 1,-4 L 1,4 L -1,4 L -1,-4 Z" />
        </group>
    </group>

</vector>
```

What is my problem:
When I click the button - I use the resource with an arrow pointing up. Then I animate it 180.0 degrees down. 
When I click again - I switch to arrow pointing down and re-animate it back up to 0.0.

The bug I've encountered: When I tap the button between the animations (so for example when the arrow is at 90.0 degrees) the animations jumps to the beginning. 
I tried using the `<animated-selector>` but I guess it didn't fix my problem. (or maybe it was me implementing it wrong)

I may switch to Property Animation, but it sounds like a lot of work. So before I do that - is there a better solution for this, using stuff I've showed you?

Comment: Maybe because when clicking again on it you start again the animation, you can disable the button until the animation is finished

Comment: @Chol terrible idea - this would kill the overall responsiveness.